# Oscilloscope Run/Stop output signal

Tags: signal, oscilloscope

[image]

Hi, guys. Does anyone know what causes the multiple waves at a time when you run the oscilloscope? But when you stop (pause) the oscilloscope, you get one wave a time (picture on the answer column).

---

[image]

This is the screenshot of the signal output when I pressed the stop button on the oscilloscope.

Comment: You have Acq Mode on *Preserve*, try *Sample*.

Comment: Taka, please take the tour to get an idea of how to use this website. This is not a forum, it's a Q&A site.

Answer (score 1):

It is not multiple waves at the same time, but rather multiple waves captured at *different* times overlapping on the display.

These appear on the screen for two reasons:

- First, your waveform has zero crossings at multiple places in its cycle, and your trigger is set near zero, so it can be satisfied at multiple points in time, meaning the re-triggerings won't cause the waveform to approximately align as they would with a better chosen trigger condition (say near an absolute maximum).
- Next, your scope is operating in a fancy persistence mode where it simulates the delay phosphor of an analog CRT by slowly fading old traces, or even holds them permanently in a uniquely digital manner.  As Steve G. points out in a comment, changing this mode may cause the scope to only display a single copy of the waveform at a time.

And of course if you use the scope in some other mode, such as a single shot capture without re-triggering, you would only see one copy of the waveform.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Chris! I thought there were multiple noises at a time form my input. (which destroys the law of physics) But it was just output error of the oscilloscope?

Comment: Not output error, we might say "user error" - or far more fairly, the fact that a modern oscilloscope is a very capable tool bursting with features, and it takes time to learn to how to get it back to even a fairly basic mode.

Comment: So the output from my microphone should look like the one I stopped and screenshot it? The reason I asked is that after this input from the microphone I am planning to reverse the signal to cancel the noise.

Comment: Both are valid representations of a small fraction of an effectively infinite amount of information.  *Neither* is likely going to even touch the surface of a project as complex as what you seem to be intending, which is far, far beyond the scope of your question, and likely beyond the scope of a new question that would even be allowed here.  At any rate, for audio you'll find a sound card and audio software (perhaps *audacity*) far more useful than a scope.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, this is not an error. This is the intended operation of the oscilloscope. It all comes down to a combination of your trigger settings and the oscilloscope's waveform update rate.

First, let's look at your triggering. In this instance, you're using the default trigger settings - rising edge trigger with a 0V threshold level. This means that every time the oscilloscope sees a rising edge moving from below 0V to above 0V, the scope will trigger. It will capture/acquire data, and plot it to the screen. In your signal, this appears to happen quite often.

However, this is happening more frequently than your eyes can handle (and more frequently than the display refreshes. So in Run mode, the scope overlays multiple captures/trigger instances on top of each other. When you hit "stop" or "single" you are telling to scope to drop out of Run mode and only display 1 acquisition/capture.

If you hit "Stop" it will display the most recent capture, and if you hit "Single" it will capture & display the next signal that meets your trigger requirements.

Check out the Keysight Labs YouTube channel, which I help create content for. We have a ton of oscilloscope info on topics like this!

Answer (score 0):

When you have noise added to a repetitive waveform the waveform is no longer triggered at the zero crossing of the repetitive wave with a 125uS period.

To capture this you need to remove the lower frequency noise in the signal OR the trigger using an HPF that attenuates the LF noise.  But since this bandwidth of the noise and the signal overlaps the amplitude jitter causes jitter in the trigger of the recurring wave.

The phase jitter is a direct function of the SNR of the signal or the trigger signal's amplitude jitter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tony! What is a jitter?

Comment: The blur in Signal edges vs time of your photograph except at centre trigger